# Remove Child of Root actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild, document-root

I've created 4 instances of Notes and I have them moving to the right until their x value is greater than 100. Once they're there, how do I remove them? I ran a trace statement and confirmed that the parent of these instances is root (root1 to be exact). If I type
    root.removeChild(this); 
I get an error saying "call to a possibly undefined method removeChild"
If I type
    removeChild(this);
I get an error saying "The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller". Full code is posted below. The last line before the }'s at the end is the problem line. Thanks so much for the help!

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

[Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")]
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
private var speed:int = 8;
[Embed(source="../lib/Dodgethis.jpg")]
public var Notes:Class;
public var numnotes:Number;
public var timer:Timer = new Timer(500, 1)
public var rootContainer:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer (root);

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point
        timer.start();
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, testevent);

        }

    private function testevent(e:Event = null):void {
        trace("testevent has run");
        appear();
    }

    private function appear() {
        var arr1:Array = new Array;
        numnotes = 4;

        for (var i = 0; i < numnotes; i++)
            {
            trace (i);
            var nbm:Bitmap = new Notes;
                stage.addChild(nbm);
                nbm.y = i * 50;
                arr1.push(nbm);
                addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
        }

    }
    private function loop (e:Event):void {
        this.x += speed;
        trace(this.x) ;
        if (this.x > 100) {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            trace ("Event listener was removed");
            //removeChild(this);
            //rootContainer.removeChild (nbm);
            /*trace(this.contains)


            trace(this.name)
            trace(this)*/
            trace(this.parent.name); //root
            removeChild(this);
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this in the loop function

```
e.target.parent.removeChild(e.target);
//or
stage.removeChild(e.target);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the notes to stage. So you need to remove them from stage.

```
stage.removeChild( note );
```

You can only remove a child from its parent, not from any other container. So calling removeChild on a different container will always fail